# Integers from excel files become floats?

Tags: python, xlrd

I use `xlrd` to read data from excel files.

For integers stored in the files, let's say `63`, the `xlrd` interprets it as `63.0` of type `number`.

Why can't `xlrd` recognize `63` as an integer?

Assume `sheet.row(1)[0].value` gives us `63.0`. How can I convert it back to `63`.

Comment: It'd just be int(yourfloat), wouldn't it? http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int.  I won't post as an answer - I feel like I may be insulting you and probably missed something.

Comment: @stackuser10210 I wonder why integer 63 in the spread sheet becomes 63.0.

Comment: No idea.  I'm not familiar with xlrd and I've never done similar.  If they're really integers in excel (ie, A1=63.0, B1=Int(A1), and you're getting 63.0 from B1, then I can understand the problem.  Sorry I don't have an answer.

Comment: There are no integers in Excel.  Just floating point numbers in drag.

Comment: Since at least [1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values) there's an [Int64 type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#construction) (note the capital I) which can also handle missing values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the different cell types in the [documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#sheet.Cell-class), it seems that there isn't any integer type for cells, they're just floats. Hence, that's the reason you're getting floats back even when you wrote an integer.

To convert a float to an integer just use `int`:

```
>>> int(63.0)
63
>>> int(sheet.row(1)[0].value)
63
```

Comment: Woolly terminology. `63.0` is already an integer. `int(some_float)` truncates its arg to an integer and returns that value as an `int` object.

Comment: But how do you know whether it's a float or an int?

Answer (score 26):

Excel treats all numbers as floats. In general, it doesn't care whether `your_number % 1 == 0.0` is true or not.

Example: `A1 = 63.0, B1 = 63, C1 = INT(A1), A2 = TYPE(A1), B2 = TYPE(B1), C2 = TYPE(C1)`
You'l see that `TYPE()` returns 1 in each case.

From the Excel Help:

```
If value is   TYPE returns 
Number        1 
Text          2 
Logical value 4 
Error value   16 
Array         64
```

`xlrd` reports what it finds. `xlrd` doesn't mangle its input before exposing it to you. Converting a column from `(62.9, 63.0, 63.1, etc)` to `(62.9, 63, 63.1, etc)` would seem like a pointless waste of CPU time to me.

Comment: +1.  It doesn't get any better than hearing it straight from `xlrd`'s author.

Comment: Well, actually Number type is 2, and Text type is 1

Answer (score 12):

The answer given by jcollado is alright if you have all the entries in the excel sheet as numbers which are integers.
But suppose you have a number which is a float you can always put a check condition like -

```
    if i==int(i): //checking for the integer:
      print int(i)      // solving your problem and printing the integer
    else:
      print i           //printing the float if present
```

Hope you find this useful :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm reminded of this gem from the `xlrd` docs:

> **Dates in Excel spreadsheets**
>
> In reality, there are no such things. What you have are floating point
>   numbers and pious hope.

The same is true of integers.  Perhaps minus the pious hope.

Answer (score 2):

## Since 1.0.0 try [convert_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html)

Following [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64332661/678486) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249860/how-to-check-if-float-pandas-column-contains-only-integer-numbers): the [pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) method tries to convert columns to other (at present experimental) `dtypes` in the returned `DataFrame`. These `dtypes` include [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), [`boolean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) and [`StringDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype) which also handle missing values. See [*Working with text data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) for motivation to convert to `string` columns and [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html#kleene-logical-operations) on [kleene logical operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Kleene_and_Priest_logics) for the advantages of a `boolean` column.

Answer (score 0):

I've written code which tries to convert numbers to strings as they are displayed by Excel. The approach works works at least for integer numbers and numbers with two digits after a comma. It should work also for many other formats.

The idea, screenshots and code are here: http://uucode.com/blog/2013/10/22/using-xlrd-and-formatting-excel-numbers/