# How to check if float pandas column contains only integer numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(10),columns=['v']).astype(float)
```

How to make sure that the numbers in `v` are whole numbers?
I am very concerned about rounding/truncation/floating point representation errors

Comment: How will testing for integers allay concerns about floating-point errors? Do the values come from integers, and you are concerned they have changed? Or are they the results of calculations whose mathematical properties are such that exact results would be integers?

Comment: these values come from integers. However during processing often they are casted to float64

Comment: The only errors that can occur in handling integers in floating point are rounding and overflow errors when converting from one format to another. When converting integer to floating-point, if the precision does not suffice to represent the value exactly, it will be rounded. However, the value it will be rounded to will be another integer, due to the nature of floating-point. Therefore, testing whether all values in an array are integers will provide no information about whether any rounding errors have occurred.

Comment: If the task is to ensure that values converted from integer to floating-point do not incur any rounding error, then it suffices if no integer exceeds the precision of the significand of the floating-point format. For example, IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary has a 53-bit significand, so conversion of any integers up to 2^53 in magnitude will be not incur any rounding error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Comparison with `astype(int)`

Tentatively convert your column to `int` and test with `np.array_equal`:

```
np.array_equal(df.v, df.v.astype(int))
True
```

---

#### `float.is_integer`

You can use this python function in conjunction with an `apply`:

```
df.v.apply(float.is_integer).all()
True
```

Or, using python's `all` in a generator comprehension, for space efficiency:

```
all(x.is_integer() for x in df.v)
True
```

Comment: WHat is the tolerance of allclose compared to is_integer?are they a call to the same function?

Comment: @ErroriSalvo No, the mechanisms are slightly different. With `allclose`, the tolerance is very small to account for floating point inaccuracies. With `is_integer`, the function actually checks for whole numbers. The mechanism is slightly different but the end result is the same.

Comment: `allclose` is incapable of determining that a number is an integer unless the tolerance is set to 0, at which point it becomes a test for equality. Furthermore, as stated in my comment to the question, testing for integer values does not accomplish the OP’s actual goal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil okay, I've changed that to array_equal. By the way, this may be an XY problem, but it is still useful to know how to do this with numpy/pandas, so I've gone ahead and answered anyway. I appreciate the criticism (and the downvote).

Comment: `df.v.apply`: not sure if this works, after `df.v` it is a numpy ndarray, which does not have the method `apply`. Do you mean `apply_along_axis`?

Answer (score 19):

Here's a simpler, and probably faster, approach:

```py
(df[col] % 1  == 0).all()
```

To ignore nulls:

```py
(df[col].fillna(-9999) % 1  == 0).all()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check multiple float columns in your dataframe, you can do the following:

```
col_should_be_int = df.select_dtypes(include=['float']).applymap(float.is_integer).all()
float_to_int_cols = col_should_be_int[col_should_be_int].index
df.loc[:, float_to_int_cols] = df.loc[:, float_to_int_cols].astype(int)
```

Keep in mind that a float column, containing all integers will not get selected if it has `np.NaN` values. To cast float columns with missing values to integer, you need to fill/remove missing values, for example, with median imputation:

```
float_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['float'])
float_cols = float_cols.fillna(float_cols.median().round()) # median imputation
col_should_be_int = float_cols.applymap(float.is_integer).all()
float_to_int_cols = col_should_be_int[col_should_be_int].index
df.loc[:, float_to_int_cols] = float_cols[float_to_int_cols].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, *Pandas v1.0+* offer the [`convert_dtypes()` utility](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html), that (among 3 other conversions) performs the requested operation for all dataframe-columns (or series) containing only integer numbers.

If you wanted to limit the conversion to a single column only, you could do the following:

```py
>>> df.dtypes          # inspect previous dtypes
v                      float64

>>> df["v"] = df["v"].convert_dtype()
>>> df.dtypes          # inspect converted dtypes
v                      Int64
```

Answer (score 1):

On **27 331 625 rows** it works well. **Time : 1.3sec**

```py
df['is_float'] = df[field_fact_qty]!=df[field_fact_qty].astype(int)
```

This way took **Time : 4.9s**

```py
df[field_fact_qty].apply(lambda x : (x.is_integer()))
```