# Python pandas shows all ints in csv as floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to verify that values in a CSV are `integers` and report an error if they are not. Being an amateur, I thought I had it figured out if the user entered '8k' or whatever as a value by using this:

```
    try:
        int(value)
    except ValueError:
        print("No Deal, Howie!")
```

I completely overlooked the possibility that a user can enter 8.8, which is unacceptable as well. Unfortunately, I can't use:

```
if type(value) == int
```

because pandas dataframe turns all the `ints` in my CSV into `numpy.float64`. What can I do about this?

Comment: When using `.read_csv`, there is a dtype parameter to specify the column types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if float pandas column contains only integer numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249860/how-to-check-if-float-pandas-column-contains-only-integer-numbers)

Comment: You asked almost this same question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043034/check-all-items-in-csv-column-except-one-python-pandas  Didn't the answers to that question work for you?

Comment: Unofortunately, none of those answered my question, Craig. Just left me more confused. Buuuuut, the .is_integer() worked! So thank you Alollz :) ...I couldn't seem to find that link in my google searches Craig, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty safe method that will capture a bunch of different integer types.

```
import numpy as np

def num_is_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, (int, np.integer)):
        return True
    else:
        try:
            return x.is_integer()
        except AttributeError:
            return False
```

---

```
num_is_int(7)
True

num_is_int(7.0)
True

num_is_int(np.int16(7))
True

num_is_int(7.1)
False

num_is_int('7')
False

num_is_int(None)
False
```

Comment: Nice. I just learn that `float` has method `is_integer` :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int()` like this:

```
if value == int(value)
```

Comment: it will always be `float` though

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the value is an integer you can convert it into a string, use .split() method and search for zeros.

An example:

```
A=5.000006
print(A)

B=str(A).split(sep='.')
print(B)
print(B[1])
integer=1

for b in B[1]:#B[1] is the decimal part of A
    if b!='0':
        integer=0
```

If integer=0, this is not an integer,
If integer=1 this is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python's builtin [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function. Like this:

```
if not isinstance(value, int):
    print("No Deal, Howie!")
```