# Retrieve int value from Excel if it is an int Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I've got the following data that I am retrieving from an Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

As you can see, there are rows that have floats and others that have ints.
Using my below program, if I retrieve each value using `worksheet.cell_value(row, col)`, then each int is being retrieved as a float. For example, 321 in the Random Number column is being retrieved as 321.0.

I do not want to have decimal points if the number does not include it. I've seen a couple of examples online, specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825681/3480297) one, but I've not been successful with any of the answers.

So far, I've got:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("demo.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

num_rows = worksheet.nrows
num_cols = worksheet.ncols

for row in range(num_rows):
    for col in range(num_cols):
        if isinstance(worksheet.cell_value(row, col), float):
            print(worksheet.cell_value(row, col))
        elif isinstance(worksheet.cell_value(row, col), int):
            print(int(worksheet.cell_value(row, col)))
        else:
            print(worksheet.cell_value(row, col))
```

But this returns the the ints with decimal points:

```
Version
Name
Random Number
1.1
Smith
321.0
1.2
John
1234.0
2.1
Paul
123456.0
2.2
Rich
98765.0
2.3
Harvey
567.0
2.4
Jones
90909.0
```

Alternatively, I have tried:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("demo.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

num_rows = worksheet.nrows
num_cols = worksheet.ncols

for row in range(num_rows):
    for col in range(num_cols):
        if worksheet.cell_value(row, col) == int(worksheet.cell_value(row, col)):
            print(int(worksheet.cell_value(row, col)))
        else:
            print(worksheet.cell_value(row, col))
```

But I get an error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Version'

Comment: `I do not want to have decimal points if the number does not include it.` - Other values in that column are actual floats, so I'd recommend keeping them like that (keeping whole column one type), and just adjust printing format.

Comment: As for the error - you also grab headers. You need to check that your value if float first: change the if line to `if isinstance(worksheet.cell_value(row, col), float) and worksheet.cell_value(row, col) == int(worksheet.cell_value(row, col))`

Comment: @h4z3 I was just thinking, and there isn't a use case for my project where a column would have mixed floats and ints. It's either one or the other. I've edited my question to reflect this. How would I adjust the printing format in that case?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by your second answer. Why would I be checking if the value is an instance of float and also of int type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on the right track with the second code example, but I had to make sure that any string is being evaluated as well:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("demo.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

num_rows = worksheet.nrows
num_cols = worksheet.ncols

for row in range(num_rows):
    for col in range(num_cols):
        if isinstance(worksheet.cell_value(row, col), str):
            print(worksheet.cell_value(row, col))
        elif worksheet.cell_value(row, col) == int(worksheet.cell_value(row, col)):
            print(int(worksheet.cell_value(row, col)))
        else:
            print(worksheet.cell_value(row, col))
```

Result:

```
Version
Name
Random Number
1.1
Smith
321
1.2
John
1234
2.1
Paul
123456
2.2
Rich
98765
2.3
Harvey
567
2.4
Jones
90909
```